# Unable to find comments from URL using Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I am working on `Android`. I want to extract comments from a web page using `jsoup` library. I am doing in this way. But could not do that. Can anyone help?

```
 public void fun() {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tribune.com.pk/story/1164751/federal-govt-dodged-chinese-govt-cpec/").timeout(10 * 1000).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements pa = doc.getElementsByClass("span-12 last");
        int count = 1;
        for (Element iter : pa) {
            System.out.println( iter.text());
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why did it not work, what was the issue?

Comment: @Calum It is not finding the exact `class` I think so. Nothing happens. Programe closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues here:

1. Your program closes because the server expects to get a `userAgent` string and returns you a `403 error`.
2. The comments are located under the "li-comment" class.

This code works for me:

```
Document doc = null;
try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tribune.com.pk/story/1164751/federal-govt-dodged-chinese-govt-cpec/").timeout(10 * 1000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0")
                .get();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
Elements el = doc.getElementsByClass("li-comment");
for (Element e : el) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
    System.out.println("-----------------");
}
```

You should also handle the case that li-comment is emtpy or does not exist, in case that there are no comments on the page.

Comment: As I am using Android. So, there is no need of `userAgent()`. Right? Second thing is: I saw the source code (`ctrl+u`) of `http://tribune.com.pk/story/1164751/federal-govt-dodged-chinese-govt-cpec/` but the comment are in the class `span-12 last`. It should return the text. Is'nt it?

Comment: Well, the code that you have posted does not use the userAgent, searches for the span-12 class but it also does not work, right? You can do it your way, but mine works...

Answer (score 0):

**on button click i used this..**

public void fetchData(View v) {

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Data is fetching from The Hindu wait some time ",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                // get the Document object from the site. Enter the link of
                // site you want to fetch
                /*
                 * Document document = Jsoup.connect(
                 * "http://javalanguageprogramming.blogspot.in/") .get();
                 */
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(
                        "http://www.thehindu.com/").get();
                title = document.text().toString();

                // Get the title of blog using title tag
                /* title = document.select("h1.title").text().toString(); */

                // set the title of text view

                // Get all the elements with h3 tag and has attribute
                // a[href]
                /*
                 * Elements elements = document.select("div.post-outer")
                 * .select("h3").select("a[href]"); int length =
                 * elements.size();
                 */
                Elements elements = document.select("div.fltrt")
                        .select("h3").select("a[href]");
                int length = elements.size();

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    // store each post heading in the string
                    posts += elements.get(i).text();

                }

                // Run this on ui thread because another thread cannot touch
                // the views of main thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        // set both the text views
                        titleText.setText(title);
                        postText.setText(posts);

                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: I am talking about this link dear `http://tribune.com.pk/story/1164751/federal-govt-dodged-chinese-govt-cpec/`